# Unable to pass parameters to connection class using Scala-Spark on IntelliJ

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have recently completed studying Scala & Spark. I am trying to do an exercise to read data from a table present on Postgres DB using JDBC connection. I created a Scala SBT Project and created a properties file to store all the connection properties.

### [image]

I have the following properties in connections.properties file:

```
devHost=xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
devPort=xxxx
devDbName=base
devUserName=username
devPassword=password
gpDriverClass=org.postgresql.Driver
```

I created a DBManager class where I initialize the connection properties:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.util.Properties
class DBManager {
  val dbProps = new Properties()
  val connectionProperties = new Properties()
  dbProps.load(new FileInputStream(connections.properties))

  val jdbcDevHostname = dbProps.getProperty("devHost")
  val jdbcDevPort     = dbProps.getProperty("devPort")
  val jdbcDevDatabase = dbProps.getProperty("devDbName")
  val jdbcDevUrl      = s"jdbc:postgresql://${jdbcDevHostname}:${jdbcDevPort}/${jdbcDevDatabase}?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory" + s",${uname},${pwd}"

  connectionProperties.setProperty("Driver",dbProps.getProperty("gpDriverClass"))
  connectionProperties.put("user", dbProps.getProperty("devUserName"))
  connectionProperties.put("password", dbProps.getProperty("devPassword"))
}
```

In a Scala Object I am trying to use all these details as below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import com.gphive.connections.DBManager

object PartitionRetrieval {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val dBManager = new DBManager();
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport().appName("GP_YEARLY_DATA").getOrCreate()
    val tabData = spark.read.jdbc(dBManager.jdbcDevUrl,"tableName",connectionProperties)

  }
}
```

I referred this [link](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html) to create the above code.
When I click on 'build' on the project:
I see that the connections.properties file is not loaded properly in the code I've written.
Could anyone let me know how can I correct the mistake ?

---

Comment: are you sure you completed studying spark and scala? you should go back and study how to call variables of another class from an object in scala.

Comment: Yes. But these concepts were not taught. Hence I am trying these by myself.

Comment: these are general concepts which doesn't need to be taught

Comment: Agreed, just that its different from Java, I need to properly workout how it's done here.

Comment: its same as in Java. just create an instance of DBManager class and call connectionProperties